# combination different button -into one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I have created 1 button, using CSS, javascript + jquery. When someone press start it loads the bar(using Setimeout). This works fine. I have and another button that I use it for doing other things inside my page.I want to have one button for those 2 buttons.

```
<style>
        /* progress bar container */
        #progressbar{
            border:1px solid black;
            width:200px;
            height:20px;
            position:relative;
            color:black; 
        }
        /* color bar */
        #progressbar div.progress{
            position:absolute;
            width:0;
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#369;
        }
        /* text on bar */
        #progressbar div.progress .text{
            position:absolute;
            text-align:center;
            color:white;
        }
        /* text off bar */
        #progressbar div.text{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
```

Javascript + Jquery code

```
(function($){
    function run() {
        var x = 100,
            y = 100,
            z = 10,
            count = 0;

        /*
        This helper function implements a for loop using CPS. 'c' is
        the continuation that the loop runs after completion. Each
        'body' function must take a continuation parameter that it
        runs after doing its work; failure to run the continuation
        will prevent the loop from completing.
        */
        function foreach(init, max, body, c) {
            doLoop(init);
            function doLoop(i) {
                if (i < max) {
                    body(function(){doLoop(i+1);});
                }
                else {
                    c();
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        Note that each loop body has is own continuation parameter
        (named 'cx', 'cy', and 'cz', for clarity). Each loop passes
        the continuation of the outer loop as the termination
        continuation for the inner loop.
        */
        foreach(0, x, function(cx) {
            foreach(0, y, function(cy) {
                foreach(0, z, function(cz) {
                    count += 1;
                    $('#progressbar').reportprogress((100*(count))/(x*y*z));
                    if (count * 100 % (x*y*z) === 0) {
                      /*
                      This is where the magic happens. It yields
                      control to the javascript event loop, which calls
                      the "next step of the foreach" continuation after
                      allowing UI updates. This is only done every 100 iterations because setTimeout can actually take a lot longer than the specified 1 ms. Tune the iterations for your specific use case.                   
                      */
                        setTimeout(cz, 1);
                    } else {
                        cz();
                    }
                }, cy);
            }, cx);
        }, function () {});
    }

    $('#start').click(run);
})(jQuery);
```

Now,If I use this code on body  ,

```
<

div id="progressbar"></div>
    <input id="start" type='button' value='start' />
```

It works fine unti now.I want instead of using

> <input id ="start" type 'button' value='start'/>

I want to use that button

```
<button onclick="openWin()" id='c_login' class='btn
    btn-primary'>Login : Player Name<img alt="gif" height="115"
    src="login.gif" width="185" /></button><br>
```

because on that button I am doing and other things..
I tried to do it something like this

```
<input id ="start" type 'button' value='start' onclick="openWin()" id='c_login' class='btn
    btn-primary'>Login : Player Name<img alt="gif" height="115"
    src="login.gif" width="185" />
```

but it didn't worked...

Comment: Can you please show the code for openWin()?

Comment: @Doug , the openWin function ,is a function I did to combine the input start..it doesn't matter .It is what I have tried ..not needed this function

Comment: In your last piece of markup, you have "type 'button'" instead of "type='button'".  Note the missing equal-sign.  It might have been a mistake when you were creating this post, but can you please confirm the syntax of your markup?

Comment: @DougF it is type='button'. I just not thinking when I give what I have tried..My mistake while typing..Ignore the last code ,it was my thoughts on how can I create it

Comment: I was able to get in working in a bin at https://jsbin.com/gaxowihugu/edit?html,js,output so feel free to check it out.  I used the button code you provided (the one in the button tag) with one change, which was to give the button an ID of "start".  I also had to find the progress bar script, which I found at https://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/jqueryprogressbar.js but let me know if you were using another script since this script is old.